# Unable to login to my account from GUI interface, 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, lightdm, authentication, guest-session

Unable login to my account from GUI interface, only as Guest. When trying to login, within a few seconds I'm sent back to the login screen. Further, after trying some fixes, when trying login as admin, login screen is not returning back, get only a blank screen and it does not proceed further. Can only Guest login.
Login from tty4 terminal is OK.

**.xsession-errors** contains only these lines:

```
Can't save user-dirs.dirs
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init:/home/username/.config/upstart: Unable to load configuration: Permission denied
init: dbus pre-start process (4902) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: Try to run `xdg-user-dirs-update --force` from a TTY.

Comment: Tried this command, the output is `Can't save user-dirs.dirs`

Comment: After trying a few solutions, GUI access  to admin account has been fixed. Basically,  the last command I tried from TTY was `'sudo chown -R username:username /home/username'` where `'username'` is your account name. Then logout and rebooted PC.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and found that [the solution @minto posted as a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803966/unable-to-login-to-my-account-from-gui-interface-14-04/987151#comment1214166_803966) worked for me, along with changing the `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` permissions.

To summarize:

```
sudo chown -R username:username /home/username
```

Then logout and reboot.

If that didn't work then check out [SiddharthaRT's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/527764) on changing `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` permissions in answer to 
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).